# How to fix Auth0 handleAuthentication redirect?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, auth0

Hi I am implementing auth0 in my angular 2 application. After successfully logging in the callback component does not redirect to my home page.

```
  public handleAuthentication(): void {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.setSession(authResult);
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
      } else if (err) {
         this.router.navigate(['']);
         console.log(err);
      }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Any luck on getting this to work? Having the same issue.

Comment: @GetFuzzy I used window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; that worked for me

Comment: I ended up wrapping the call to router.navigate in a setTimeout() which is evil, but also does the trick.

Comment: haha, if it works for you then its great